# Salting tennis lawns

Tags: weed-control, weeds

I have heard that tennis lawns are salted to kill the weeds. So I was wondering why doesn't the salt kill the grass also ?

Comment: _"I have heard that tennis lawns are salted to kill the weeds."_ Citation needed

Comment: Suspect your source of being misinformed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ordinary salt does kill grass as well as weeds. Either your source is confusing 'salt' with 'salts of' something or other, or doesn't mean tennis lawns, but tennis courts (clay or tarmac).

Comment: Or hartrue Courts

Comment: Whatever they are, never heard of them, but artificial lawn courts too...

Comment: Hartrue is one of the media used in tennis courts. It's like clay with gravel on it. That's a very poor explanation, but it's a popular tennis court medium.